# VS Code integration with Gitlab Enterprise

Tags: visual-studio-code, gitlab, enterprise

Thanks for reading

-I have successfully integrated my Gitlab enterpise with VS Code, however, whenever I try to clone from my enterprise account from VS Code, I get the error below :

"Error: Field 'projects' dosen't accept argument 'searchNamespaces':{"response":[{"me..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.

1. Create Token for VS Code in Gitlab Settings.
2. Clone as follows:

   ```
   git clone https://${username}:${TOKEN}@REPO
   ```